# Laravel $errors not dispalying in blade

Tags: php, laravel

My login form in blade validates but wont display errors, it returns to login page with blank entries upon failure, how do I go about this?

Initially my route was defined in api.php and was getting same issue so I changed it to web.php and still same. Also value="{{old('name')}}" too dose not work.

Here is the form I wrote in the blade

```
<h5>Login Your Account</h5>    
        <!-- FORM -->
        @if ($errors->any())
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <ul>
                  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                  @endforeach
              </ul>
          </div>
      @endif
        <form method="POST" action="/login" >
        {{ csrf_field() }}
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="" value="{{old('name')}}">
                  @if ($errors->has('name')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p> @endif
              </div>


              <div class="form-group ">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{old('password')}}">
                  @if ($errors->has('password')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</p> @endif
              </div>



              <li class="col-sm-12 text-left">
              <button type="submit" class="btn-round">Login</button>
            </li>

          </form>
```

Here is my controller login function

```
public function login(Request $request){

    $validator= Validator::make($request->all(),
    ['name'=> "bail|required|max:50|exists:users",
    'password' => 'required|min:6|exists:users,password'
]
);

if ($validator->fails()){
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withError($validator);
}
else{
    if (Auth::attempt(['name'=> $request->name, 'password'=>$request->password])){
    return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Here is my web.php route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('home');
});
Route::post('/login','API\userController@login');
```

And my kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,

\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];

/**
 * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
 *
 * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];
}
```

If validation is successful, It redirects to the route I specified, but once it fails it directs back to the log in page with no error displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel's RedirectResponse class has method `withErrors()` to send validator message bag where as you are calling `withError()`.

See this from Laravel's `RedirectResponse.php`

```
/**
     * Flash a container of errors to the session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\MessageProvider|array|string  $provider
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return $this
     */
    public function withErrors($provider, $key = 'default')
    {
        $value = $this->parseErrors($provider);

        $this->session->flash(
            'errors', $this->session->get('errors', new ViewErrorBag)->put($key, $value)
        );

        return $this;
    }
```